# Number Rows Cassandra->Hadoop Input differs

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

i have a ColumnFamily with 147.968 Rows (shows "nodetool cfstats") on a 2 Node Cluster.

If i execute my Hadoop Job he shows only 90.174 Rows on "Map input records"? My Hadoop CQL Input Config is:

```
ConfigHelper.setInputRpcPort(job.getConfiguration(), "9160");
ConfigHelper.setInputInitialAddress(job.getConfiguration(), "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
ConfigHelper.setInputColumnFamily(job.getConfiguration(), KEYSPACE, "columnfamilyname");
ConfigHelper.setInputPartitioner(job.getConfiguration(), "Murmur3Partitioner");
```

Is there anything else to configure?

Answer (score 1):

What's your input/output format? It's better to use CqlPagingInputFormat. FTY. cql table rows are not the same as column family row, so if you use CqlPagingInputFormat you should get the same number of rows as you get it from Cqlsh.